# Getting KeyError when using shortest_path of NetworkX and ShapeFile

Tags: python, shapefile, shortest-path, networkx

I have a shapefile of all street segments in Los Angeles County that I have made sure is clean.  I am able to use the QGIS Road Graph plugin to calculate various shortest paths, see attached as my first example.

I am getting an error when trying to use the NetworkX shortest_path on my network.  I am loading a shapefile (roughly 410,000 edges).  My route start and end points are well known and ON the network.  There are probably better data structures, but i have created a dictionary of Points with values of what i believe to be the street segment keys, though not sure (from docs:  Coordinate tuples are used as keys).

Error:

```
.... weighted.py", line 359, in _dijkstra
  for u, e in G_succ[v].items():
KeyError: ((-118.3162743390968, 34.25880839639892), (-118.31575202245774, 34.25880723483486))
```

I verified that this street segment listed in the KeyError is in the edges list as I wrote all edges to file.

I am now going to start diagnosing the weighted.py code.

Core code snippets:

```
def InitRoadGraph():

    self.roadGraph = nx.read_shp(self.roadsrc)
    self.StreetNodeFromDict = {}
    for edge in self.roadGraph.edges(data=True):
        self.StreetNodeFromDict[edge[0]] = (edge[0], edge[1])

def GetStreetIDFromNodeSimple(self, geometry_point):

    return self.StreetNodeFromDict[geometry_point]

def GetShortestRoute(self, srcPoint, dstStreetSegmentID): 

    srcSegmentID = self.GetStreetIDFromNodeSimple(srcPoint, "FNODE_")

    shortestRoute = nx.shortest_path(self.roadGraph, srcSegmentID, dstStreetSegmentID)[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

Answer (score 1):

I have confirmed that in networkx 1.11, the keys of the network dictionary are the start node coordinates, not the start and end node segments as i would suspect.  Though significant changes have been made to the read_shp method through 2.1, I don't see a change to this behavior.  It would seem we'd want the begin/end even though that might not be unique either.

Also, attached is my network though it doesn't appear to have attached to my original post.

Finally, i would think the read_shp would calculate a weight attribute.  I may try to add that and make a pull request if that makes sense.

[image]